# Flutter foregroundColor property is throwing error in my project

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter version 3.0.0

I am having a TextButton, but I get an error on the foregroundColor property showing, `The named parameter 'foregroundColor' isn't defined.` I also tried uisng flutter 3.3.3, but still get the same error.

[image]

```
TextButton(
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the MaterialStateProperty in the Flutter 3+ versions

```
 textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.whtie,), 
      ),
    ),
```

See also https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons